# Cant separate two columns in csv file from R

Tags: r, csv, bigdata

I tried to add two columns into a new csv file from R, and the problem that the two columns are in column A, instead to be in separate columns

you can see my code and the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFlA7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHiXy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHiXy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mutate()` from `tidyverse` package.

One built-in dataset `cars` in Rstudio and I use it as the demo

```r
car_new <- mutate(cars, time = dist/speed, distance_new = dist + 100)

#>    speed dist      time distance_new
#> 1      4    2 0.5000000          102
#> 2      4   10 2.5000000          110
#> 3      7    4 0.5714286          104
#> 4      7   22 3.1428571          122
#> 5      8   16 2.0000000          116
#> 6      9   10 1.1111111          110
#> 7     10   18 1.8000000          118
#> 8     10   26 2.6000000          126
#> 9     10   34 3.4000000          134
#> 10    11   17 1.5454545          117
```